# Avoid BIGINT user profile harvesting

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, http

One of the advantages of using a GUID over a BIGINT as a primary key for users profiles is that it is much more difficult to harvest user profiles using a flurry of GET requests. You lose some of this added security of GUID's when you use sequential GUID's, as the next GUID used becomes somewhat predictable.

So how do you avoid this issue when using BIGINT's, as they're highly predictable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the following:

- Store the ID in session instead of querystring
- Encrypt the ID and pass the encrypted value in querystring (for MVC, you can even do [seamless too](https://onallthingsweb.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/asp-net-mvc-seamless-routing-encryption/))
- Pass in the name instead, and always use the name to translate to the ID

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Man, this site is just gross at times.

Comment: Unless something orders of magnitude better comes along within the next 5 minutes, I'll check this answer. Thanks.